# Although I use isset, I get an undefined index error

Tags: php, isset, undefined-index

I know it asks too many time. But the `isset` function is not solve my problem.

```
$get = (isset($this->settings[$set['id']])) ? $this->settings[$set['id']] : '';
```

> Notice: Undefined index: id in \public_html\settings.php on line 419

Comment: whats the specific error you are getting ?

Comment: Probably _Undefined index `id`_ ;-)

Comment: yes I am thinking of the same, that's what I am suggesting on my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe, `$set['id']` must check, like this:

```
$set_ = isset($set['id']) ? $set['id'] : '';
$value = isset($this->settings[$set_]) ? $this->settings[$set['id']] : '';
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to check if the variable is set before using it as an argument.

```
$get = isset( $set['id']) ? $this->settings[$set['id']] : '';
```

Comment: Probably need both `isset` checks.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply add it to the isset call

```
$get = isset( $set['id'],$this->settings[$set['id']]) ? $this->settings[$set['id']] : '';
```

You can use multiple arguments in isset.  This is roughly equivalent to doing this:

```
$get = isset($set['id']) && isset($this->settings[$set['id']]) ? $this->settings[$set['id']] : '';
```

This can be easily tested with this code:

```
$array = ['foo' => 'bar'];
$set = []; //not set
#$set = ['id' => 'foo']; //uncomment to test if set


#using [] to add an element to a string not an array
$get = isset($set['id'],$array[$set['id']]) ? $array[$set['id']] : '';

echo $get;
```

When `$set = ['id' => 'foo']` the output is `bar` if you leave that commented then the output is an empty string.

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b7585d69191900c949ee91888bc6682c384e31e3)